# WHERE clause with 6 months condition

Tags: sql, db2

I am working on trying to list every item that hasn't changed in the last month but when I run this query:

```
select * from AGLT.LTB0040  WHERE wdate> current_date - 6 MONTHS
```

I get an error message saying that the value is not valid. I have checked the dates listed in the field and they are 20160101. Any idea on where I have gone wrong?

Comment: Could you try `current date` instead of `current_date`

Comment: In standard SQL the interval needs to be specified like this: `interval '6' month` not sure if DB2 supports that

Comment: What's the data type of `WDATE`?

Answer (score 0):

If date column is a representation of a date make a string or numeric comparison.

If the date is a 8 char field

```
WHERE wdate >= varchar_format(current   
timestamp- 6 months,'YYYYMMDD')
```

If the date is 8,0 field

```
WHERE wdate >= cast( varchar_format(current   
timestamp- 6 months,'YYYYMMDD')  as decimal(8,0))
```